# How to use soft cascade in the latest opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have already download the latest opencv from github and successed compile it. I notice that the latest version realize the soft cascade algorithm and I want to test it. But I don't know how to detect a pedestrian use this method. Is there anybody know it? My platform is vs2010+win64+opencv3.00 ，
Briefly, the problem is that I don't know how to load the existing xml file to scascade. I try the load function but the param is Filenode. If there is anbody who know it can you tell me?